# Javascript / jQuery - How to convert Media and Image data into binary text format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to send a image/media through json, for that conversion needs to be done into text format. How can I achieve that through jQuery/ Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in this post [get image data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
    // original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

You need to pass the `img` tag to this function.
For further details see [Convert an image into binary data in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420384/convert-an-image-into-binary-data-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

A few times already I read that jQuery doesn't provide functionality to download binary data and have it pass on to JavaScript as a string. Then I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7370943/483113). That got me thinking and I wrote a wrapper around `$.ajax()` looking like this (yes, it's simplified to show the main bits):

```
ajaxWrapper = function(url, dataType, callback, headers) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: dataType == "binary" ? "text" : dataType,
        mimeType: dataType == "binary" ? "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" : undefined,
        headers: headers || {}
    }).done(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        callback(data, status, jqXHR);
    });
}
```

And then in case you are dealing with Unicode the callback contains this line:

```
data = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
```

or otherwise simply

```
data = btoa(data);
```

In other words if you read through the [documentation of $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you simply add a `dataType` "binary".

*Note that I use jQuery 1.7.1, but I don't see why it shouldn't work in later versions, too.*

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(…))` obviously is senseless.

Comment: @Bergi Well, actually not. If you google for base64-encoding and browser issues you will run into answers suggesting to use this.

Comment: Can you point me to it? However I haven't seen a browser where decoding is not the inverse function of encoding, even if programmed non-standard.

Comment: @Bergi First, I forgot to say that it's related to Unicode-strings. Second, this is weird. If I google for it I get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa as the third hit. However, the content of the page doesn't have that line in there any more. I will change my answer to use `unescape()`. Thanks for the hint.